# Proability analysis in Euclidean LSH

Tags: pr.probability

I am learning about LSH(Locality Sensitive Hashing) for Euclidean distance, that is, a technique to hash vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and make sure close vectors (in Euclidean distance) are hashed into the same bucket with high probability.

A typical way is to project vecotrs to a random real line $\vec{a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and segment the line into buckets. The distance of vector $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ on the real line is then $\| \vec{u} - \vec{v} \| \cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{u} - \vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$.
In practice, the random line is generated by Gaussian distribution.
Sec 4.4 in [this link](https://web.lums.edu.pk/%7Eimdad/Teaching/CS5312_Notes/Notes-14-LSH.pdf) gives a good introduction to this method.

However, I have a question about the probability analysis of this technique (Theorem 8 in [this link](https://web.lums.edu.pk/%7Eimdad/Teaching/CS5312_Notes/Notes-14-LSH.pdf)).
In the analysis, the angles $\theta$ are assumed to be uniformly distributed in $[0, \pi]$.

But I generate some random data and find that untrue.

In 2d case, the angles seems distributed uniformly in $[0, \pi]$.

[image: 2-d case]

However, in 3d case and higher dimensions, the angles concentrate on $\pi / 2$. (I know that random vectors in high dimension space are **almost orthogonal** to each other. Not sure this is related or not).

[image: 3-d case]

[image: higher dimension]

If angles between $\vec{u} - \vec{v}$ and random vector $\vec{a}$ are not uniformly distributed, then the probability analysis is wrong.

For example, in the analysis of false-positive rate, it says that if $\|\vec{u} - \vec{v}\| > 2 w$ (they are "far" from each other) where $w$ is the width of the bucket, then the probability that they are hashed into the same bucket are less than $1/3$.
$$ \| \vec{u}-\vec{v} \| \cos \theta < w \Rightarrow 2w \cos \theta < w \Rightarrow \cos \theta < 1/2$$. Since $\theta$ is random, the probability is 1/3.

For full analysis, see Theorem 8 in [this link](https://web.lums.edu.pk/%7Eimdad/Teaching/CS5312_Notes/Notes-14-LSH.pdf).

Did I misunderstand something or have some mistake in the code? Appreciated it if someone can help.

Comment: Can you summarize why that analysis assumes a uniform distribution of angles? or how a different assumption would affect the conclusions? Without such summaries, the request to check an argument given elsewhere is off-topic.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you, I have added a simple description of the analysis, and provided links to full analysis.

Comment: "Sensity" is not a word.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, it is "sensitive".